# the least odd natural number $k$ such that the equation $x^2\equiv k\pmod {2017}$ doesn't have integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I'm looking for the least odd natural number $k$ such that the equation $x^2\equiv k\pmod {2017}$ doesn't have integer solution.

I'm using the Eisenstein lemma, we have $\big(\frac{a}{p}\big)=(-1)^{T(a,p)}$ when $a$ is an odd integer and $p$ is an odd prime number with $p\nmid a$. Following my calculations we have:

$T(3,2017)=336$ and $T(5,2017)=607$. Since $\big(\frac{3}{1017}\big)=(-1)^{336}=1$ and $\big(\frac{5}{1017}\big)=(-1)^{667}=-1$. So, we have $k=5$.

Am I made any mistakes?

Comment: Just as a alternate argument we can use quadratic reciprocity.  $2017 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ so $\left( \frac 3{2017}\right)= \left( \frac {2017}3\right)=\left( \frac 1{3}\right)=1$ and  $\left( \frac 5{2017}\right)= \left( \frac {2017}5\right)=\left( \frac 2{5}\right)=-1$

Answer (score 3):

The least quadratic non-residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ is always a prime. By exaustive search:
$$\left(\frac{2}{2017}\right)=1,\quad \left(\frac{3}{2017}\right)=1,\quad \left(\frac{\color{red}{5}}{2017}\right)=-1$$
hence $\color{red}{5}$ is the answer.

$\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3$ are surely quadratic residues since $2017$ is a number of the form $24k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

For amusement value: the discriminant $2017$ has class number one. The principal form is $x^2 + 43 xy - 42 y^2,$ equivalent over $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ to
$u^2 + uv - 504 v^2.$ Meanwhile, the form does represent $-1$ integrally, which is automatic as $2017 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is prime. The Lagrange cycle for the principal form therefore shows all the small primes represented, which are the same as those which are quadratic residues. The line labelled 2 shows that $2$ is represented, line 14 shows that $3$ is represented. Line 40 shows $7.$ Line 32 shows $11.$ The bit about $2$ means that there is an integer solution to $s^2 - 2 t^2 = 2017.$ Look at that, $45^2 - 2 \cdot 2^2 = 2017$

Discriminant $8068$ also has class number one, so $x^2 - 2017 y^2$ does very well. However, it is not possible to have $x^2 - 2017 y^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4,$ so $2$ itself is out of the picture.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 43 -42

  0  form              1          43         -42


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   1 43 -42   delta  -1     ambiguous  
1  form   -42 41 2   delta  21
2  form   2 43 -21   delta  -2
3  form   -21 41 4   delta  10
4  form   4 39 -31   delta  -1
5  form   -31 23 12   delta  2
6  form   12 25 -29   delta  -1
7  form   -29 33 8   delta  4
8  form   8 31 -33   delta  -1
9  form   -33 35 6   delta  6
10  form   6 37 -27   delta  -1
11  form   -27 17 16   delta  1
12  form   16 15 -28   delta  -1
13  form   -28 41 3   delta  14
14  form   3 43 -14   delta  -3
15  form   -14 41 6   delta  7
16  form   6 43 -7   delta  -6
17  form   -7 41 12   delta  3
18  form   12 31 -22   delta  -1
19  form   -22 13 21   delta  1
20  form   21 29 -14   delta  -2
21  form   -14 27 23   delta  1
22  form   23 19 -18   delta  -1
23  form   -18 17 24   delta  1
24  form   24 31 -11   delta  -3
25  form   -11 35 18   delta  2
26  form   18 37 -9   delta  -4
27  form   -9 35 22   delta  1
28  form   22 9 -22   delta  -1
29  form   -22 35 9   delta  4
30  form   9 37 -18   delta  -2
31  form   -18 35 11   delta  3
32  form   11 31 -24   delta  -1
33  form   -24 17 18   delta  1
34  form   18 19 -23   delta  -1
35  form   -23 27 14   delta  2
36  form   14 29 -21   delta  -1
37  form   -21 13 22   delta  1
38  form   22 31 -12   delta  -3
39  form   -12 41 7   delta  6
40  form   7 43 -6   delta  -7
41  form   -6 41 14   delta  3
42  form   14 43 -3   delta  -14
43  form   -3 41 28   delta  1
44  form   28 15 -16   delta  -1
45  form   -16 17 27   delta  1
46  form   27 37 -6   delta  -6
47  form   -6 35 33   delta  1
48  form   33 31 -8   delta  -4
49  form   -8 33 29   delta  1
50  form   29 25 -12   delta  -2
51  form   -12 23 31   delta  1
52  form   31 39 -4   delta  -10
53  form   -4 41 21   delta  2
54  form   21 43 -2   delta  -21
55  form   -2 41 42   delta  1
56  form   42 43 -1   delta  -43
57  form   -1 43 42   delta  1     ambiguous            -1 composed with form zero  
58  form   42 41 -2   delta  -21
59  form   -2 43 21   delta  2
60  form   21 41 -4   delta  -10
61  form   -4 39 31   delta  1
62  form   31 23 -12   delta  -2
63  form   -12 25 29   delta  1
64  form   29 33 -8   delta  -4
65  form   -8 31 33   delta  1
66  form   33 35 -6   delta  -6
67  form   -6 37 27   delta  1
68  form   27 17 -16   delta  -1
69  form   -16 15 28   delta  1
70  form   28 41 -3   delta  -14
71  form   -3 43 14   delta  3
72  form   14 41 -6   delta  -7
73  form   -6 43 7   delta  6
74  form   7 41 -12   delta  -3
75  form   -12 31 22   delta  1
76  form   22 13 -21   delta  -1
77  form   -21 29 14   delta  2
78  form   14 27 -23   delta  -1
79  form   -23 19 18   delta  1
80  form   18 17 -24   delta  -1
81  form   -24 31 11   delta  3
82  form   11 35 -18   delta  -2
83  form   -18 37 9   delta  4
84  form   9 35 -22   delta  -1
85  form   -22 9 22   delta  1
86  form   22 35 -9   delta  -4
87  form   -9 37 18   delta  2
88  form   18 35 -11   delta  -3
89  form   -11 31 24   delta  1
90  form   24 17 -18   delta  -1
91  form   -18 19 23   delta  1
92  form   23 27 -14   delta  -2
93  form   -14 29 21   delta  1
94  form   21 13 -22   delta  -1
95  form   -22 31 12   delta  3
96  form   12 41 -7   delta  -6
97  form   -7 43 6   delta  7
98  form   6 41 -14   delta  -3
99  form   -14 43 3   delta  14
100  form   3 41 -28   delta  -1
101  form   -28 15 16   delta  1
102  form   16 17 -27   delta  -1
103  form   -27 37 6   delta  6
104  form   6 35 -33   delta  -1
105  form   -33 31 8   delta  4
106  form   8 33 -29   delta  -1
107  form   -29 25 12   delta  2
108  form   12 23 -31   delta  -1
109  form   -31 39 4   delta  10
110  form   4 41 -21   delta  -2
111  form   -21 43 2   delta  21
112  form   2 41 -42   delta  -1
113  form   -42 43 1   delta  43
114  form   1 43 -42


  form   1 x^2  + 43 x y  -42 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 2017 dSqrt 44  M_Ratio  1936
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-965532677013781482875198088170183835928234466523769  -42440482758478505176147113435578355104819436064102752
-1010487684725678694670169367513770359638558001526256  -44416503120217965353692480891262309300386228532152777
=========================================
```